# Selected vs Selection in Xpages application layout control

Tags: xpages

This is SO confusing. I have an Xpage application built with the application layout control. I have 2 Title Bars which each have a navigation element in them with two views each.

I want the selected Title Bar and view to be highlighted. I understand that somehow this involves the Navigation Path and the use of the selected and/or selection properties,, but I do not understand how they work or interact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can these answers help you? [How do you use the Selected property of the navigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644262/how-do-you-use-the-selected-property-of-the-navigator)

You need to set the navigationPath property on each XPage and this must match the selection property (using regex) on the navigation control.

**Updated with answer to the comment below**

Here's an example XPage for the Home tab and the navigation control for Home:

```
<xc:layout navigationPath="/Home/XPage1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xc:layout_menu_home xp:key="facetLeft"></xc:layout_menu_home>
        <xc:content_xpage1 xp:key="facetMiddle"></xc:content_xpage1>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:layout>
```

The layout custom control uses the xe:applicationLayout to control the layout. In this case it has a custom property called navigationPath which is used in the example XPage above. The corresponding navigationPath property of the xe:applicationLayout must be set to this custom property:

```
<xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout">
    ...
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:oneuiApplication 
            navigationPath="${javascript:compositeData.navigationPath}">
```

Here's part of xe:applicationLayout for handling the two tabs in your layout custom control:

```
<xe:this.titleBarTabs>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="/xpage1.xsp" label="Home" selection="/Home/.*"></xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="/xpage3.xsp" label="Tips" selection="/Tips/.*"></xe:pageTreeNode>
</xe:this.titleBarTabs>
```

Here's an example navigation control for Home:

```
<xe:navigator id="navigator1" >
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:pageTreeNode page="/xpage1.xsp" label="XPage 1" selection="/Home/XPage1"></xe:pageTreeNode>
        <xe:pageTreeNode page="/xpage2.xsp" label="XPage 2" selection="/Home/XPage2"></xe:pageTreeNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
</xe:navigator>
```

Comment: I have seen that other post and it doesn't help. I have four Xpages, two that belong to one tab and two that belong to the other tab. Say tab one is "Home" and tab to is "Tips". I have a custom control for application layout for all xpages. I have a navigation control for each tab. So there are 4 Xpages, 2 navigation controls, one for each Title Tab, and one custom control for all xpages. Please give me an example of what I would enter into the Navigation Path for the custom control and what I would enter fro the selection property of the Title Tabs to get the tabs to "light put.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I am still unable to get it to work. Here is my confusion. I have xpage1, xpgage2, and xpage3. I have the following cc: content_xpage1, layout, layout_menu_home, and navigation. I do not understand why there are two application layout custom controls, and I am not sure which one goes in xpages one. I put the called "layout" in xpage1, and then I put layout_menu_home in the left facet and the xc content in the middle facet. I put the navigator in the left facet of the layout cc control.

Comment: I made sure that all these selections are correct. When I run this on the web it looks alright, EXCEPT nothing is every selected. Is there some sample template on github that has this. I have dug through the team room template and can't figure this out. I could package this up and stick it on github if you would be so kind as to look at it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. xc:layout_menu_home is your navigation control for your Home XPages. Does that help? Feel free to post on Github.

Comment: OK I put it on Github: https://github.com/bryanschmiedeler/Xpages       Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The db is encrypted. Please upload a new version without encryption

Comment: Very sorry about that, I always forget. Copied db and turned off encryption.

Comment: Here's a working copy: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1467184/TipsGitHub.nsf. I updated/deleted custom controls and very importantly added the custom property navigationPath to the applicationLayout property navigationPath. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? Does it make sense now?

Comment: Henrik, Yes! It makes perfect sense now. I think the way I was structuring my app made it harder for me to understand how to make this work, but now I do. Thank you so much for helping, and sorry for the delay in getting back to you, my Mom is in the hospital so my work has been sporadic.

Comment: Great to hear that it helped