# XPages Navigation Control

Tags: xpages

I am attempting to get to grips with an XPages project after a colleague has moved on and would appreciate if someone would clarify one thing on one control.

The Xpage is named Home and it has a component named LeftOneUI that provides a horizontal list of menu options.  The top of the source of the Home XSP looks like this;

```
<xc:OneUILayout id="cc4cconeuilayout"
  navigationPath="/OneUI/Home">
  <xp:this.facets>
      <xp:panel xp:key="LeftColumn" id="panel4">
         <xc:LeftOneUI id="cc4ccLeftOneUI"></xc:LeftOneUI>
      </xp:panel>
```

The top of the source for the LeftOneUI looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"  
     xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
   <xe:navigator id="outline">
     <xe:this.treeNodes>
         <xe:pageTreeNode page="home" label="Home"
              selection="/OneUI/Home">
         </xe:pageTreeNode>
```

I understand the "Home" part.  I understand the label part.  I understand what a pageTreeNode does.  I understand how the Custom Control is inserted into the XPage etc.  But what I can't understand so far is, in the "selection" part how does the /OneUI/ part work??  Can someone explain this please?

I just can't seem to see where the /OneUI/ comes into it although I feel it is something to do with the "Navigation Path".

Thanks in advance

AJF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selection property is using regEx to match itself with the navigationPath custom property.

See this answer as well: [How do you use the Selected property of the navigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644262/how-do-you-use-the-selected-property-of-the-navigator)

Comment: Thanks for response Per Henrik.

Okay.  So this all happens because the NAVIGATION PATH is declared as "/oneUI/Home" in the Home.XSP - Yes?  But is the /oneUI/ part declared by the developer in the Navigation Path?  If not that what determines if it is /oneUI/ or /somethingelse/?

Thanks again

AJF

Comment: Yes, and yes. Naming it "/OneUI/" is a decision the developer has taken. It's a good idea to make the navigationPath property consist of two parts since it makes it easy to highlight tabs in the titleBar - see Declan's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9649400/785061

Comment: Thanks Per Henrik.  That helps.  This is what happens when you inherit a project that has not been completely documented.  AJF

Comment: Wait, you mean it was partially documented? You were lucky!