# Change the looks of selected navigator item

Tags: xpages

I've been playing around with Extension Library Navigator for a while and I can't figure out how to make the selected (or the current opened pages basic node) node to change any of the looks properties, for example font or color. I'm trying to do that so that user can tell what page is currently opened. Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: The xe:navigator already supports marking a menu element as selected. See this question and the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644262/how-do-you-use-the-selected-property-of-the-navigator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, which is not as simple as the one suggested by Per, is to do the customization via a bit of script.

For example, I have built my site navigation with pure HTML and bootstrap.

My link HTML looks like this

```
<a id="YOURLINKIDHERE" href="vwBringUpsByDate.xsp">Bring ups</a>
```

When a page loads, you can then then use the below script to customize your selected menu item exactly how you like, fonts, colours, backgrounds etc just by referencing the link ID....

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[$("*[id$='YOURLINKIDHERE']").css('background-color', '#eeeeee');]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Not ideal, as you have to put the script on each page that you want to modify a menu link with, but gives you some good customization options...